# How to rearrange table cells on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

Briefly, I have the following table and want to rearrange the table cells in a different way on smaller screens.
Apologies, I know I should provide what I have already tried and sounded mad easy when I saw it but it is going 3hours that I am now staring at it trying to find a better **possible** way to achieve this.
Any thoughts or code to start with are appriciated.

[image]

and want it to have this look on smaller screens

[image]

Comment: Did you try using media queries?

Comment: see there is that image(message icon) on the left on the smaller screen @soulLess

Comment: I am trying to use  grid and see, but people seemed to advise me not to use divs while dialing with tables @soulLess

Comment: as @souless said try media query for screen sizes https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: I don't know if it is just me but there is a big rearrangement dome over there @Asker , I was trying to escape the use of javascript but I don't know how to

Comment: if you can share the code we can try to come to some sort of a solution

Comment: Cool, let me try what I have in mind if it looks ugly and not reliable I shall tag you @Asker